# How can I exit out from an infinitely runnng loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops

Is it possible to stop an infinite loop from running at all?

Right now I am doing something like this:

```
var run = true;

loop ({
  if(run) {
  whatever
  }
}, 30),
```

Then when I want to stop it I change `run` to `false`, and to `true` when I want to start it again.

But the loop is always running whatever I do. It just not executing the code inside.

Is there a way to stop it completely? and make it start again when I want?

Comment: I don't understand your code, could you post the actual one? Is `loop` a function?

Comment: @Liso22, what loop you mean ? you can exit `for` and `while` with `break`, `setTimeout` with flag, `setInterval` with `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetInterval will give you a loop you can cancel.

```
setInterval ( "doSomething()", 5000 );

function doSomething ( )
{
  // (do something here)
}
```

Set the interval to a small value and use clearinterval to cancel it

Answer (score 5):

If I am understanding your question correctly, what you need is the `break` keyword. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp)'s an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
function infiniteLoop() {
    run=true;
    while(run==true) {
        //Do stuff
        if(change_happened) {
            run=false;
        }
    }
}
infiniteLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly what you are looking for, but you could try [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).

var intervalId = setInterval(myFunc, 0);

```
function myFun() {
    if(condition) {
        clearInverval(intervalId);
    }
    ...
}
```

setInterval will also not block the page. You clear the interval as shown with `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop

```
while(run){
    //loop guts
}
```

When `run` is false the loop exits. Put it in a function and call it when you want to begin the loop again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that javascript only has a single thread to run on.  This means that while you are infinitely looping nothing else can happen.  As a result, it's impossible for your variable to ever change.

One solution to this is to use `setTimeout` to loop with a very small time passed to it.  For example:

```
function doStuff(){
   if(someFlag){
      // do something
   }

   setTimeout(doStuff,1);
}

doStuff();
```

This will give the possibility for other actions to make use of the thread and potentially change the flag.